# Maatwebsite, How to download excel using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to download excel file using Ajax call in Laravel.

I can download using href directly to controller, But I don't think I can send Object through url

```
let excel_file = $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "api/../excel/previewExport",
    data: {headers : headObject},
    dataType: "json"
});
```

But it return raw excel data in browser response instead of download.

What Should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create link with `data` href and download xls data in file format.

```js
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls",
   success: function (d){
   var a = document.createElement("a");
   a.download = "filename.xls";
   a.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,"+encodeURI(d);
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
   }
});
```

If this not downloading original file then you should use links because no options left:

```
window.open('api/../excel/previewExport','_blank');
```

Comment: i guess ill go with window.open option then, thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, i noticed that the size of original file and downloaded file are different.